# Download Multiple Files to Zip - Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, files

I have added a wrapper to display my files on a visualforce page.  The wrapper includes a checkbox.  I want to download all checked files at once.

The working html tag is as follows:

```
<apex:outputLink styleClass="btn" target="_blank" 
                style="text-decoration:none;padding:1px;"
                value="/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/{!fileIdsToDownload}?" >
                    Download Checked Files
         </apex:outputLink>
```

And my code to update the fileIdsToDownload is below:

```
  //Set Variable used to capture all file id's to download
  public void DownloadCheckedFiles(){
       //string for file ids to download separated by /
     String fileIdsString = null;     
     
     for(fileWrapper fw : wrapFileList){
       if(fw.pickme == True){
          if (fileIdsString == null){
            fileIdsString = fw.converWrap.id;
          } 
          else{
           fileIdsString = fileIdsString + '/' + fw.converWrap.id; 
          }
       }
     }
      
    fileIdsToDownload = fileIdsString;
      //clear out temp variable when done
    fileIdsString = null;
    system.debug(LoggingLevel.Info, '3 here is update list ' + fileIdsToDownload);

  }
```

I have an action region on the text boxes that runs the DownloadCheckedFiles method.  But what I would like to do is to use a button that loops through the checkboxes and triggers the download.  The way I have it now, the page refreshes after each checkbox is checked or unchecked.  I was unable to figure a way to handle the download in my apex method. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Fred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VF controller code should look like this (I renamed your variables to be more concise and follow conventions). Note use of getter to return the concatenated FileIds

```
public String downloadableFileIdsAsString {
  get{  // use getter to return concatenated fileIds as serveltShepherd wants
    Id[] downloadableFileIds = new List<Id>();
    for (FileWrapper fw: this.fileWrappers) {
        downloadableFileIds.addAll(
          fw.pickMe 
            ? new List<Id>{fw.converWrap.id}
            : new List<Id>());
    }
    return String.join(downloadableFileIds,'/');
  } private set;

 // Action Method - downloadCheckedFiles
 public void downloadCheckedFiles() {}
```

and your VF page should have this:

```
<apex:outputLink styleClass="btn" target="_blank" 
      style="text-decoration:none;padding:1px;"
      value="/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/{!downloadableFileIdsAsString}?" >
                Download Checked Files
</apex:outputLink>
```

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a better way to trigger the download as part of the button rather than using the outputlink?  I would prefer not to have the page rerender after each checkbox is clicked or unclicked.

Comment: Use actionRegion to limit scope of rerender.  Command buttons can initiate actions

Comment: Could I expand my setter on my wrapper object so that when someone checks a box on one of the records, it triggers updating my variable with all the id's?

Comment: Why? The wrapper maintains state, the getter fetches the selected items but only when needed

Comment: The code you posted is not working so I'm trying to figure out why.  It seems that the getter you provided is on the "downloadableFileIdsAsString"  So when the values on the wrapper change, nothing is getting triggered.  I'm thinking the getter/setter needs to be on the wrapper list.  and in the setter I need to update downloadableFileIdsAsString  I'm not sure if that is correctd but the downloadableFileIdsAsString is not getting update when a checkbox is selected/deselected with the code you provided.  thanks!!

Comment: Without seeing your entire controller and entire relevant bits only VF page it is hard to respond

Comment: I understand.  Is there any way I can move this, "<apex:outputLink styleClass="btn" target="_blank" 
                    style="text-decoration:none;padding:1px; background:lightblue"
                    value="/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/{!fileIdsToDownload}?" >
                        Download Checked Files
             </apex:outputLink> " functionality into an apex method?  That would allow me to check the values of the checkboxes and then download the files in a zip.

Comment: The download has to be initiated from the browser

Comment: So that initiation can't be a button?

Comment: Nice. Is this somewhere documented by Salesforce? I'm a bit surprised to find this solution "only here".

Comment: @FelixvanHove - I don't think so; I figured this out by observing the URL when requesting multiple files as zip